# How to pass response from volley to a variable

Tags: android, android-volley

i have following

```
ImageView mImageView;
mTxtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);
String url = "http://my-json-feed";
String xSession = "";

JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        /*


 {
      "message": "Session created",
      "session": "d4f7d26799c720eb6b09daa97a1b7e64",
      "result": {
        "id": "331339814848696320",
        "name": "Administrator",
        "email": "cyz@jsjsjsjsjsjsjsjsjsj.com",
        "username": "admin"
      }
    }
            */
      xSession = response.getString("session");
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

on the response i can see  response.getString("session") has the value but xSession is not populated?
why xSession is not being populated? please help!

Comment: can u show the response jsonobject?

Comment: You declared xsession but assigned value to xSession. Where's xSession declared?

Comment: sorry bro i mistype here "xSession " to xsession on declaration in this question but in code it is always "xSession".

Answer (score 1):

Java languague is case-sensitive. Where did you declare xSession variable? Then, the right one you want to process is xsession or xSession? Please review or post more relevant code.

Comment: sorry bro i mistype here "xSession " to xsession on declaration in this question but in code it is always "xSession".

Comment: Pls post the content of `JSONObject response` (you can use `Log.i("ABC", response.toString();`), then post the logcat information

Comment: Check entire your project, if there's another place besides the request that xSession updated

Answer (score 0):

Try to log the response inside `onResponce`  . if it reached there then make sure the value of xsession used only after receiving response and it is set